# Android App Playing Music Without Internet

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mp3

I'm developing a meditation app. Suppose I include the mp3 files in the raw file, and the application's size increases to around 600 MB. If I get the music files from a URL, the application will require Internet access. I'd like to reduce the size of my application, but I also need music files. What can I do? I am a new developer.

Comment: What about downloading the files in the first startup of the app, and keeping the files for when offline? It will require internet access, but it will be needed just the first time a user opens the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, use a codec that is more efficient than MP3.  You could encode your audio with Opus or AAC and reduce your bitrate a bit while retaining decent quality.

You'll still have a large amount of data usage though.  You claim that you *need* all 600 MB of this.  Is that really true?  If you need it, you need it.  There's nothing else to it.  But, you might consider non-technical solutions.  For instance, streaming a variety of music online, but reducing the available music for the few times the user is offline.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do?

You have a tricky problem.

- You could compress the mp3 files, but that will reduce the quality of the audio.
- If you have the time and skills, you could transcribe the music as Midi (synthesizer) files and include a Midi player in your application.  But the music will *sound* like synthesized music, and it would be a lot of work to do the transcribing.

Comment: Mp3 files already are compressed.  You're not going to achieve significant additional reduction.  You could re-encode at a lower bitrate with a quality drop, but with modern versions of mp3 using variable bit rate encoding that gain will be minimal.